# PHP quiz correct answers counter in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have developed a simple quiz in PHP (Code igniter framework). At the moment the quiz can validate if the user answer is correct or not. Next I am trying to score the user for every correct answer. Therefore I would need an increment for every correct answer.
At the moment I have this:
Trying to get the current value of the counter from the view, which at the beginning of the quiz should be zero.

In the view:

```
<input type=hidden name=counter value="<?php echo $counter ?>
```

Controller getting value from view:

```
$c = $this->input->get('counter',false);
```

Then using the starmodel class calling increment function in the controller:

```
$counter = $this->Starmodel->increment($c);
```

This is my function:

```
function increment($counter){
        $counter = $counter + 1;
        return $counter;
}
```

Loading the view with the result from the function:

```
$person = $this->load->view('starview', array('iscorrect' => $res,
                                               'question' => $person['question'],
                                               'name' => $guess,
                                               'results' => $counter));
```

Displaying the results in the view:

```
<?php echo $results ?>
```

Would appreciate some help on how I could do this.
Thank you

Comment: Would be useful to mention which framework you're using.

Comment: @Daan ohh. Sorry. Using **Codeigniter**